# Matlab border around figure

Tags: matlab, plot

In attached image the output looks boring to me. Is it possible to have the subplots enclosed in a border?

Note: This question is not specific to publishing only but in general, say for exported images also.

Thanks[image]

Postscript: I actually need this:
[image]

Comment: It is unclear (to me at least) what you want! Can you make an image of how you want it to look, or at least explain what you mean by "enclosed in a border"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a box like in [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/289660)
making your code:

```
close all
figure()
padd=0.04
axes('Position',[padd padd 1-padd*2 1-padd*2],'xtick',[],'ytick',[],'box','on','handlevisibility','off')
subplot(1,2,1)
imagesc(magic(2))
subplot(1,2,2)
imagesc(magic(3))
```

This yields

[image]

And you can change the `padd` to be bigger or smaller

Answer (score 0):

I obtained this just by plotting lines of different thickness [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HKey.png).

The text was added with Inkscape though.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you want to do, you can obtain borders inside a figure using `uipanels` http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uipanel.html like this:

[image: Plots in uipanels]

Code is:

```
u=uipanel('Title','MainPanel')
u1=uipanel('Parent',u,'BorderType','line','HighlightColor','k','Title','Subpanel 1','Position',[0,0,0.5,1])
u2=uipanel('Parent',u,'BorderType','line','HighlightColor','k','Title','Subpanel 2','Position',[0.5,0,0.5,1])
axes1=axes('Parent',u1)
imagesc(magic(2))
axes2=axes('Parent',u2)
imagesc(magic(3))
```

Of course you can change border widths, colors, titles and such